# Is there a way to know why some computers in our office are losing connection to windows active directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have set up a Windows active directory in AWS and has a VPN connection to that instance from our office static ip.

Sometimes when we change a user's password using an Active directory their Windows PC login password do not change with it. We have a Google password sync with AD and the Google account password is changed and users are still logging in with their old password to their PC. We have to add our DNS server address and add the PC to the domain again and it will work fine.

I am very new to windows servers and I do not know what is causing this. What can be done to prevent this and what is causing this?

I do not know how to troubleshoot this since I do not know when this is happening.